# How to limit duplicate values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

First of all, I apologize for my lack of English. I hope you do understand what I'm trying to explain here.

So basically I need to build a function that would limit the number of duplicate values inside an array.

The reason I need to do this is that I'm building a system that would divide numbers into groups and every group has to have the same amount of numbers.

EDIT: Random number represents the group number.

I've written a function do this but for some reason, it is not working properly.

```
function jagaTiimid($max, $liiget, $tArvLength, $tArv){
      $tiimid = []; //Starting array
      for($z=0;$z<$liiget;$z++){
          $numbers = [];
          $rn = randomNumber($tArvLength, $tArv, $numbers); //Generate a random number for a group, etc group 1, group 2, group 3 
          $mitu = countInArray($tiimid, $rn); //Check how many times that number has occured in array
          if($mitu == $max){ //If it equals to maximum number of times then... 
             $rnUus = randomNumber($tArvLength, $tArv, $numbers); //generate a new random number
             while($rnUus == $rn){
               $numbers = [];
               $rnUus = randomNumber($tArvLength, $tArv, $numbers);
             } //loop until the new generated number doesn't equal to old rn.
             $tiimid[] = $rnUus; //if it doesn't equal to $rn then push into array
          }else{
             $tiimid[] = $rn;
          }
      }
      return $tiimid;
}
```

For some reason the number still occures more than it is suppose to.

Basically how it shouldn't end up is.

[image]

As you can see, one group(group 2) occurs more times than other group but it should be equal for both groups.

EDIT: CountInArray();

```
function countInArray($array, $what) {
  $count = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
      if ($array[$i] === $what) {
          $count++;
      }
  }
  return $count;
}
```

Comment: What "lack of English" are you talking about?

Comment: @arkascha I just figured that I'm not a native speaker so maybe you guys/gals don't quite understand what I'm explaining.

Comment: replace `while($rnUus == $rn)` with `while(countInArray($tiimid, $rnUus) >= $max)`

Comment: @IlyaBursov It's not working, the outcome is still the same. Also, I forgot to mention that I've already tried it.

Comment: then you have error in countInArray

Comment: @IlyaBursov Actually no. Check the original post, I added that that part of code there. The PHP nor AJAX error function isn't giving me any errors.

Comment: @drpzxc and? it has error, you're starting from 1

Comment: @drpzxc Yeah why are you starting count at 1?

Comment: @IlyaBursov - It was just a typo, sorry :)

Comment: I've tried your code with my fix - works like a charm, probably you have error somewhere else

Comment: What do you need `$numbers` for?

Comment: @trincot This random number function isn't actually meant for this purpose. This array is just needed for that function to work.

Comment: @IlyaBursov Damn, I'm still clueless as of why it isn't working for me but i'll mark your answer anyway.

Comment: And please, guys let me know before you downvote. I'm pretty sure that my question didn't deserve that downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first random pick hits a number that is already used `$liiget` times, the inner loop kicks in, but it does not check whether the newly generated random number already occurs `$liiget` times.

For efficiency I would keep track of the number of times a number has been used. Also, you could benefit from a safety net, in case there really is no number any more that would not exceed the maximum recurrence.

It is not necessary to have a nested loop. The code would look like this:

```
function jagaTiimid($max, $liiget, $tArvLength, $tArv){
    $tiimid = []; //Starting array
    $counts = []; // Helper for quick count
    $tries = 0; // Counter to avoid infinite looping
    while (count($tiimid) < $liiget && $tries++ < 100) {
        $numbers = [];
        $rn = randomNumber($tArvLength, $tArv, $numbers); //Generate a random number for a group, etc group 1, group 2, group 3 
        if (!isset($counts[$rn])) $counts[$rn] = 0; // initialise on first occurence
        if ($counts[$rn] < $max) {
            $tiimid[] = $rn; // add it to the result
            $counts[$rn]++; // ... and adjust the count
            $tries = 0; // reset the safety
        }
    }
    return $tiimid;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace while($rnUus == $rn) with while(countInArray($tiimid, $rnUus) >= $max) 
– Ilya Bursov